# Return the whole string from a one word search and unreachable code

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview

I am having problems with this code. It returns only the first word in the string. l need the whole string returned in the `Column` if someone enters one or both words plus only some characters in the string.

The search is done in a `TextBox` from the first `DataGridView` `Column` in. It's a collection list stored in an `XML` file loaded into the `DataGridView`.

Also I have an `i++` in `for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)` that states it's unreachable.
I am not sure why either.

It is just a binding list as a collection.

[Picture of WinForms App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veYLV.png)

```
//Search DataGridview Button 
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = searchtextBox.Text.ToLower(); /
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

    try 
    {
        bool valueResult = false;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                //if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToLower().Equals(searchValue))
                if (row.Cells[i].Value != null && row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue))
                {
                    int rowIndex = row.Index;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                    valueResult = true;
                    searchResults.Text += "=> " + searchValue + " " + Environment.NewLine.Trim();
                }
                break;         
            }
        }

        if (!valueResult)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find " + searchtextBox.Text, "Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)box
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }         
}
```

Comment: the code you posted is truncated and does not compile. please make sure to include a minimal, complete example so we're able to reproduce your problem. especially the `catch` would be interesting, maybe also remove the try..catch as long as you're debugging so exceptions are not ignored. the `i++` is unreachable because there is an unconditional break inside the loop - it will never have more than one iteration.

Comment: `searchResults.Text += "=> " + searchValue + " " + Environment.NewLine.Trim();` here is your problem, you are building result from values user enters not from the ones you find.

Comment: there are two simple mistakes which a debugger would reveal. make yourself familiar with the debugger, and use it. #1 is the break, remove it: otherwise you will always get matches only with the first column. #2 your search result should not consist of the search term, but the content of the matching row, `row.Cells[i].Value`

Comment: Thanks removing the break helped with the hidden code situation. Also I have edited the question put the full code block. Sorry I thought I pasted the whole thing into the question.

Comment: All of you helped me fantastic working perfect.

Comment: Thanks everyone....Removed break and fixed hidden code on i++, and removed searchValue replaced with row.Cells[0].Value. I thought it was the searchValue and break issue. Thanks for everyone clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Removed break and fixed hidden code on `i++`, and removed `searchValue` replaced with `row.Cells[0].Value`.
I thought it was the `searchValue` and break issue.

Thanks for everyone clarifying the problem.

```
//Search DataGridview Button 
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = searchtextBox.Text.ToLower(); //simple search Full row from text box with button
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

    try //try to run the following code
    {
        bool valueResult = false;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            //i++
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)//for loop to enable iteration throught the gridview rows
            {
                //if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToLower().Equals(searchValue))

                if (row.Cells[i].Value != null && row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue))
                {
                    int rowIndex = row.Index;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                    valueResult = true;

                    searchResults.Text += "=> " + row.Cells[i].Value + " " + Environment.NewLine.Trim();//outputs search results to multi line textbox separated by commas and trimmed white space of   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```